# AJAX Jquery MVC5 404 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, url-routing

I am very new to MVC and I have got a question about MVC / AJAX Calls.

I am trying to get the data back from MVC Controller but it keeps saying 404 Error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:6481/MDT/Detail?id=4935"
```

My Javascript call is as below and I hardcoded id:1245 as the test.  I tried to switch POST and GET, but still no luck

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'MDT/Detail',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: 1245
    }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    fail: function(data) {}
 });
```

I have tried it without JSON.stringify and the error is still the same (404)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'MDT/Detail',
    data: {
        id: 1245
    },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    fail: function(data) {}
});
```

The following is the code in the Controller..

```
    [Route("MDT/Detail/{id}")]
    public JsonResult Detail(int? id)
    {
        ITS.Models.ComputerDetail cp = GetDataFromDatabase(id.Value);

        return Json(cp, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I have checked in Firebug and the parameters are passed correctly as following:

I couldn't figure out what I have done wrong.  Could you please help me with this error?

If I used (http://localhost:6481/MDT/Detail/1245), it works fine and returns the JSON object but I couldn't call this MVC method from JQuery AJAX.

Comment: If you don't stringify (and there is no need to), then you need to remove `contentType: "application/json",`

Comment: `url: '/MDT/Detail',` You can try adding a `/` leading slash before MDT.

Comment: And use `url: '@Url.Action("Detail", "MDT")',` so you generate the correct url which would be `/MDT/Detail`

Comment: I have tried /MDT/Detail, MDT/Detail/, /MDT/Detail/ or Url.Action, Url.Content, etc and it's still showing 404 error.

Comment: Forgot to mention that, the same code works till I added Route Attributes because I want a feature to use http://localhost:6481/MDT/Detail/1245 rather than http://localhost:6481/MDT/Detail?id=1245

Comment: In that case you should show your `RouteConfig.cs` file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must send id not like param but like part of url. Change your code to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'MDT/Detail/1245',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    fail: function(data) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer is just not to use

```
JSON.stringify({ id: 1245 })
```

just pass

```
data:{ id: 1245 }
```

with

Also POST request working after adding **[HttpPOST]** Attribute to Controller Action.

And MVC default routing is {Controller}/{Action}/{id} as per your ajax call Route is  http://localhost:6481/MDT/Detail?id=4935 and id is taken as Query String Parameter so for that you need to use Route as http://localhost:6481/MDT/493.

Comment: This is incorrect and will actually cause more issues.

Comment: Yes,Sorry but use it url as  url: 'MDT/Detail/'+id, not use id in "data" it takes "id" as Query string arameter. But MVC default routing is {Controller}/{Action}/{id}

Comment: It can also work with POST without changes. For that you have to add attribute [HttpPost] above Your Controller Action.